# Perform functions on arrays

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array that I got from and API like this

```
 array(
    'data' => array(
        'id' => 0,
        'attributes' => array(
            'title' => 'title'
        ),
        'itemdetails' => array(
            'id' => 0,
            'attributes' => array(
                'title' => '',
                'images' => array(
                    'original' => '',
                    'thumbnails' => array(
                        'thumb',
                        'thumb'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

So if I want to get the images I have to do

```
$array['data']['itemdetails']['attributes']['images']['thumbnails']
```

Is there a way so I can do

```
$array->getImageThumbnails()
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: No, but you can do `getImageThumbnails($array)`, if you define `getImageThumbnails`.

Comment: But isn't it possible to change the array to and object where I can perform functions on?

Comment: You can transform the array into an object, but you'd still need the object's class to define the functions you want to use. I.e. `(object)$array` won't randomly have implemented `getImageThumbnails()`.

Comment: Well, it's our own API, so now i'm writing an SDK to interact with the API.

Answer (score 1):

I might regret this, but here is a simple implementation:

```
class someClass {

    public $array;

    public function __construct($array) {
        $this->array = $array;
    }

    public function getImageThumbnails() {
        return $this->array['data']['itemdetails']['attributes']['images']['thumbnails'];
    }
}
```

Then just:

```
$object = new someClass($array);
$thumbs = $object->getImageThumbnails();
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create an object that will accept this array in its constructor, and define your desired methods on the object:

```
class MyImage {
    protected $data = array();

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data['data'];
    }

    public function getImageThumbnails()
    {
        return $this->data['itemdetails']['attributes']['images']['thumbnails'];
    }
}
```

Instantiate this object in your code once you have the data:

```
$data = getStuffFromAPI();
$image = new MyImage($data);
return $image->getImageThumbnails();
```

Comment: That's indeed possible, But in my SDK, I already have a class that pulls items from the api. In this class I do some reformats on it. Isn't it possible to define functions for that object in this SDK class?

Comment: And the API is also ours, so I can do some changes in the API class :)

Comment: @BrechtSchepens You can either add a helper method on your SDK class that does this, similar to the `getImageThumbnails($array)` comment on your question, or you can include this class in your SDK class and do all this within the SDK class.

Answer (score 0):

**How to convert multidimensional array into object:** (`Singleton` approach)

```
class ArrayConvertor {

    private static $obj;

    private __construct(){}
    private __clone(){}

    public static function convertToObject($array = []) {
        self::$obj = is_array($array) ? (object) array_map("self::convertToObject",$array) : $array;
        return self::$obj;
    }

    public static function getImageThumbnails() {  // assuming specific array structure
        $thumbs = null;
        if (is_object(self::$obj)){
            $thumbs = self::$obj->data->itemdetails->attributes->images->thumbnails;
        }
        return $thumbs;
    }
}

$obj = ArrayConvertor::convertToObject($arr);

var_dump(ArrayConvertor::getImageThumbnails());
```